# Apache SSLSessionCache configured but not used

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm trying to configure Apache 2.4 on a windows machine like this:

```
SSLSessionCache shmcb:logs/ssl_session_cache(512000)
```

The relevant module is loaded:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

I don't get any errors on startup but it seems the cache is not used. The file does not appear in the log directory and /server-status tells me:

```
SSL/TLS Session Cache Status:
cache type: SHMCB, shared memory: 524288 bytes, current entries: 0
subcaches: 32, indexes per subcache: 91
index usage: 0%, cache usage: 0%
total entries stored since starting: 0
total entries replaced since starting: 0
total entries expired since starting: 0
total (pre-expiry) entries scrolled out of the cache: 0
total retrieves since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
total removes since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
```

When I examine individual requests in the browser it also seems like the cache is not used. Do I have to activate the cache in a certain way? Perhaps in the virtual hosts configuration or something like that?

**Update: My virtual host configuration**

SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "c:\apache24\conf\example.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:\apache24\conf\example.com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "c:\apache24\conf\ca-bundle-client.crt"

```
ServerName example.com:443

<Location /balancer-manager>
  SetHandler balancer-manager

  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  BalancerMember http://localhost:9000
  # Second Member is only standby
  BalancerMember http://localhost:9001 status=+H

  ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

<Proxy *>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow From All
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9001/

# forwarding www- and .net/.de-versions of the domain as well as the ip address to example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com|(www\.)?example\.(net|de)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

The vhost on port :80 just redirects to the one above.

Comment: Same effect when using a dbm cache.

Comment: Please add your vhost config..

Comment: Did you ever solved this?

Comment: @codenamezero, I'm not sure. I'm not working on the project anymore. It's possible that we switched back to Apache 2.2